# Who implements the "other methods" in a Functional Interface - and where?

Tags: java

The "other methods" for Consumer and BiConsumer<T,U> and BiFunction<T,U,R> is andThen().

The "other methods" for Function<T,R> UnaryOperator are compose(), andThen(), identity().

The "other methods" for BinaryOperator<T,T> are andThen(), maxBy(), minBy().

The "other methods" for Predicate is and(), or(), negate(), isEqual().

The "other methods" for BiPredicate<T, U> is and(), or(), negate().

Since a Functional Interface is passed to an implementing method by a lambda expression, who will implement these other methods - and where?

**Update:** What I was trying to point out; what if the semantics of the "other methods" are not trivial or straightforward as in the example in the comments below? Consider the `Predicate` Functional Interface. If I pass in a lambda expression to an implementing method, but the `and(), or(), negate()` are not straightforward. Then the default implementation will not cover it. I suppose we would have to handroll our own custom Functional Interface that extends the original one and implements all the "other methods"?

**Update:** For Functional interfaces like `BiFunction` which has an `andThen()` other method, does this mean we would have to inherit from this interface and create a new one with a default method `andThen()`?

Comment: They're implemented in the interface itself as defaults. See for instance [Consumer.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/function/Consumer.java)

Comment: Look for the keyword `default`, for example in `default Consumer<T> andThen(Consumer<? super T> after)`.

Comment: @khelwood thank you for the link... but if the type in the Funtional Interface is generic T then how will the default know how to implement it? your link just shows andThen() calling accept() and accept() which seems like passing the buck back to the lambda expression!

Comment: What's wrong with that? `andThen()` accepts a generic argument and returns a lambda that calls a generic method. It is a generic implementation.

Comment: @khelwood What I was trying to point out; what if the semantics of the "other methods" are not trivial or straightforward as in the example you gave? I suppose we would have to handroll our own custom Functional Interface that implements them all?

Comment: The question you actually asked is "Where are the implementations of these methods?". Now you're talking about some hypothetical other methods in some other hypothetical interface? I'm not at all clear what you're getting at.

Comment: @khelwood Consider the `Predicate` Functional Interface. If I pass in a lambda expression to an implementing method, but the `and(), or(), negate()` are not straightforward. Then the default implementation will not cover it.

Comment: What do you mean they won't cover it? They *do* cover it. What is leading you to think that they do not?

Comment: I've voted to reopen. I'd prefer it if we answered your question by explaining why the default implementations are sufficient as is and don't need to be overridden, rather than closing the question. There's nothing wrong with asking!

Comment: @likejudo What do you mean by "straightforward"? A *functional interface* is an interface with **exactly one abstract method**. `and`, `or` and `negate` are the interface's *concrete* methods, which is possible by means of the `default` keyword. A lambda expression is an implementation of a *functional interface*. The compiler will deduce which method is actually implemented by means of the lambda expression, because **it has exactly one abstract method**.

Comment: So the author of a functional interface may add as many `default` methods as he likes. All of those methods are concrete methods, which are irrelevant to lambda expressions. As long as the interface has *a single abstract method*, that is, a method definition without body (something like `void hello();`), then it's sufficient.

Comment: If you extend some functional interface, say `Predicate`, and (re)implement `and`, `or` and `negate`, then it doesn't matter, this interface still contains a single abstract method.

Comment: @MCEmperor As you pointed out, "a lambda expression is an implementation of a Functional Interface". What I was trying to ask was, what if the default methods aren't consistent with the semantics of the lambda expression. In this example, what if the default implementation of `negate` is not consistent with the Predicate I pass in? In any case, the original question asked about the implementation of the "other methods". It was not clear from the Java docs that the default methods will contain the implementation.

Comment: @likejudo Well, [the docs *do* show](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) that those are `default` methods. Of course, this assumes that one knows how default methods actually work

Comment: @MCEmperor can you address the second part - "In this example, what if the default implementation of negate is not consistent with the Predicate I pass in? "

Comment: @likejudo The default implementation of `negate()` returns a function that gives the opposite of the predicate. That is what `negate()` *means* for a predicate. In what circumstance would that not be the correct result?

Comment: @khelwood  how would you define "opposite of the predicate"? Only for a numeric value, it is understood.

Comment: @likejudo No, a predicate always returns true or false. The opposite of true or false is very clearly defined. The negation of the predicate is a predicate that returns false where the original returns true, and returns true where the original returns false.

Comment: @khelwood Can you please take a look at my answer and confirm if my understanding is correct? https://stackoverflow.com/a/75126847/398348

Answer (score 1):

Well, I got the feeling you are missing something here.

Let's consider the `Predicate` interface. I stripped it down with the elements not relevant to the question.

```java
interface Predicate<T> {

    boolean test(T t);

    default Predicate<T> negate() {
        return (t) -> !test(t);
    }
}
```

This is a *functional interface*: it has **exactly one abstract method**. The authors of this interface also added a method which they named `negate`. Its implementation returns a new `Predicate` which returns the exact opposite result when its `test` method is called. They added this method because they thought it would be useful.

As you can see, the `negate` method is default, and has a method body. **Methods which have a body, are never abstract.**

> Since a Functional Interface is passed to an implementing method by a lambda expression

and

> If I pass in a lambda expression to an implementing method

Not sure what you mean here, but I think it's poorly worded. A lambda expression can only be used where a functional interface is expected. So a lambda expression **is the implementation of the only abstract method of a functional interface**. The "other" methods are not relevant to this story so far.

Say, I want to create a `Predicate` which tests if a string is equal to "Hello". A typical implementation may look like this:

```java
str -> str.equals("Hello")
```

This is (roughly) equivalent to this:

```java
class PredicateImpl implements Predicate<String> {

    @Override
    public boolean test(String t) {
        return t.equals("Hello");
    }

    public Predicate<String> negate() {
        return new Predicate<String> {

            @Override
            public boolean test(String t) {
                return !PredicateImpl.this.test(t);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

As you can see, `negate()` returns a new Predicate which captures the predicate on which the method is called, and when its `test` method is called, it is deferred to the captured Predicate, and returns the resulting boolean inversed.

A lambda expression **never implements a default method, as these are not abstract**. So `negate` is not overridden in any way at all.

---

Of course, this doesn't stop us from creating our own functional interface in order to tamper with the semantics of *negate*.

```java
public interface MyPredicate<T> extends Predicate<T> {

    @Override
    public default MyPredicate<T> negate() {
        return t -> true; // Say what?! That's not a negation!
    }
}
```

Now let's first see the "normal" predicate in action:

```java
String s = "Hello";
Predicate<String> stringIsHello = t -> t.equals("Hello");
Predicate<String> stringIsNotHello = stringIsHello.negate();
System.out.println(stringIsHello.test(s));
System.out.println(stringIsNotHello.test(s));
```

Outputs, as expected:

```
true
false
```

Now let's use our custom predicate instead:

```java
String s = "Hello";
MyPredicate<String> p1 = t -> t.equals("Hello");
MyPredicate<String> p2 = p1.negate();
System.out.println(p1.test(s));
System.out.println(p2.test(s));
```

Output:

```
true
true
```

Now does `negate` in our `MyPredicate` what you expect it to do? Absolutely not. Does the compiler prevent you from actually doing it? No, it cannot and it will not.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. For Functional interfaces like `BiFunction` which has an `andThen()` other method (with no 'obvious' implementation), does this mean we would have to inherit from this interface and create a new one with a default method `andThen()`?

Answer (score 0):

While reading the topic of Lambdas again, I had the same question come to me and I came back here as I had not understood the other comments and answers.

I think perhaps the answer is this - **the parameter to `andThen()` is another Funtional interface;** in this case, another `Consumer<T>`

```
   default Consumer<T> andThen(Consumer<? super T> after)
```

So one can have chained methods with a **different lambda** following for the `andThen` clause.

```
void foo(Consumer<T> consumer1Lambda, Consumer<T> consumer2Lambda) {

    consumer1Lambda.test().andThen(consumer2Lambda);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, whether you need to implement the method or not (or even if you can), depends on the Functional interface.  For example here is a `BiConsumer` which implements the `accept` method and then chains subsequent implementations of the `andThen` method.

```
BiConsumer<Integer, Integer> mathResults = (x, y) -> System.out
         .printf("Here are the results for %s op %s:%n%n", x, y, x,y);
 mathResults = mathResults.andThen((x,y)->System.out.printf("Addition:       %s%n", x+y));
 mathResults = mathResults.andThen((x,y)->System.out.printf("Subtraction:    %s%n", x-y));
 mathResults = mathResults.andThen((x,y)->System.out.printf("Multiplication: %s%n", x*y));
 mathResults = mathResults.andThen((x,y)->System.out.printf("Division:       %s%n", (double)x/y));
 
mathResults.accept(30,20);
```

prints

```
Here are the results for 30 op 20:

Addition:       50
Subtraction:    10
Multiplication: 600
Division:       1.5
```